# Addin jQuery Plugin to Blogger Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am having a hard time integrating a jquery plugin into my Blogger theme.
The jquery library is declared already and it working with other plugins just fine
but when i am trying to put the following script it just don't work.

I tried to put it before the /head> tag and before the /body>, and i tried this one too

```
<script>  
//<![CDATA[         



    //]]> 
</script>
```

Also i tried to injected right in the layout gadget with no success so far

Here's the script

```
<script>
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#newsTicker4').breakingNews({
                direction: 'rtl'
                themeColor: '#11cbd7',
                source: {
                    type:'rss',
                    usingApi:'rss2json',
                    rss2jsonApiKey: '5ivfzdrkuqwmoe0dgxeqvhfz0knlo7yq4fw20bt0',
                    url:'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss', 
                    limit:7, 
                    showingField:'title',
                    linkEnabled: true,
                    target:'_blank', 
                    seperator: '<span class="bn-seperator" style="background-image:url(img/cnn-logo.png);"></span>',
                    errorMsg: 'RSS Feed not loaded. Please try again.'
                }
            });
  
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error you get in devTools?

Comment: There's no error in devTools